# Can't load image in react js/ tauri

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tauri

I read binary file using tauri into react state. Console log prints correct array buffer, but when i try to use it in img tag i get error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'buffer')". I tested the same way in vanilla js and it works

```
export default function FsView(props: any) {
    const [content, setContent] = useState<Uint8Array>(() => {
        readBinaryFile(
            (props.path.replace(props.baseDir, "")+'/images/00000.jpg').replace(/\//, ''), 
            {dir: BaseDirectory.Home}
        ).then(
            (result) => {console.log(result.buffer); return result}
        )
    })
    
  return (
        <>
        <img src={URL.createObjectURL(
                new Blob([content.buffer], { type: 'image/jpg'})
            )} />
        </>
  )
}
```

I tried a lot of code configurations but this still gives me the error.

Comment: Why aren't you using [`useEffect()`](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to perform the asynchronous action?

Comment: @ 
M0nst3R i tried useEffect but still undefined error

Comment: I don't know how the code you shared even works, `useState()` does not take a callback function, it takes an initial value. Can you share the code where you tried with `useEffect()`?

Comment: @M0nst3R
`export default function FsView(props: any) {
 const [content, setContent] = useState<Uint8Array>()

 useEffect(() => {
  readBinaryFile(
   (props.path.replace(props.baseDir, "")+'/images/00000.jpg').replace(/\//, ''), 
   {dir: BaseDirectory.Home}
  ).then(
   (result) => {console.log(result); setContent(result)}
  )
 })

  return (
  <>
     <img src={URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([content.buffer], { type: 'image/jpg'})
   )} />
  </>
  )
}`

Comment: 1. You need to use useEffect.  2. You should handle the situation where content is empty (still loading) in your `return`.

Comment: @EGORLETOV please paste the code in the question, not as a comment. Also, you would still need to check if `content` is defined and `buffer` is inside it before rendering. This is because `content` starts as undefined in the state and is fetched asynchronously.